# angular 8 webpack-bundle-analyzer looking for wrong polyfill files

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

No matter what I do, after building my project I keep getting the following error:

```
Error parsing bundle asset "<path-to-project>\polyfills-es5-es2015.e1bdcd70857e70f37509.js": no such file
events.js:174
```

Which is exactly right seeing that my project creates a `polyfills-es5.e1bdcd70857e70f37509` file and a `polyfills-es2015.25bfed26497f24d6d1d7` file.

This is in a nx workspace project that I created yesterday

After every build the file names obviously changes, but it keeps looking for a mixed `es5-es2015` polyfills file.

The stats file gets created as `stats-es2015.json` and our package.json settings is: `"bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/apps/<project-name>/stats-es2015.json"`

I keep getting the error with `default` build or `production`, with `ivy` enabled or disabled, and I eve tried to remove the `es5BrowserSupport` flag, hoping there will only be one polyfills file, but it is still looking for `es5-es2015` file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this command to see if it work for you

```
ng build --prod --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json
```

My tsconfig.json

```
    "module": "esNext",
    "target": "es5",
```

Comment: Hi, this indeed seemed to work thank you. Module was already `esNext`, could you maybe elaborate on what the consequences will be of changing target from `es2015` to `es5`? Is there a way of making it work with target = `es2015`

Comment: Be careful... if you change target `es2015` to `es5` then you will increase bundle sizes!

Answer (score 0):

I can also maybe add that I think at the end of the day my solution was just to simply close all my vsCode windows.

When ever I have vsCode open I would get the `polyfills-es5-es2015.<whatever>.js": no such file` error, but when I close vsCode and run the exact same command it works...

I think it may have to do with having the angular ui plugin in vsCode, that has some kind of bundle tool as well that uses the same port as wba. So it actually has nothing to do for me with not finding the polygon file, but it still gives that error when the wba port is in use...

PS: I found this out when checking if that port was indeed in use on my machine, and it showed that it was in use by vsCode, so something in vsCode is using it and closing vsCode solved the error for me...