# Facing errors when try to build Jhipster app for production

Tags: webpack, jhipster

When i run the command: mvnw -Pprod package -DskipTests i got theses errors:

```
PROJET_DIRECTORY>npm run webapp:prod

> guineeinfo@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webapp:prod
> npm run clean-www && npm run webapp:build:prod


> guineeinfo@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT clean-www
> rimraf target/classes/static/app/{src,target/}


> guineeinfo@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webapp:build:prod
> ng build --configuration production

/ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...DeprecationWarning: 'getMutableClone' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use an appropriate `factory.update...` method instead, use `setCommentRange` or `setSourceMapRange`, and avoid setting `parent`.
/ Generating browser application bundles (phase: sealing)...Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\742.e171a2405f5767cf.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\742.b0a6c4114f06fa22.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\230.a2138959ac8ef9fb.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\170.add042f6ffb59d9a.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\207.1d837adcb0f45770.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\149.540ad7c1f077ddba.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\polyfills.9d0c3413927bcc7e.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\768.7372d2c2b1232b49.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\1.5a9ebd01376c650f.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\603.e7657787a5adfac0.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\157.d3b3bb9926846072.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\25.0a8d2f972e78f3a4.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\309.02d2d31bcdb56c32.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\runtime.0a47f77b2bcae2f3.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\743.0211d9b008f10892.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\982.83219fa0ddff78e6.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\113.2e503c811f66459d.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\696.b9082f0f6ccacf14.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\102.c5a0e5c0b14776bb.js": no such file
[INFO] Error parsing bundle asset "PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\static\main.8a914c32b295c497.js": no such file
[INFO]
[INFO] No bundles were parsed. Analyzer will show only original module sizes from stats file.
[INFO]
[INFO] Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved report to PROJET_DIRECTORY\target\classes\stats.html
[INFO] â?? Browser application bundle generation complete.
[INFO] â?? Browser application bundle generation complete.
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [982.7bfdac8536ec324c.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [696.c62403f835307afb.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [102.0d09ee10c1af6f27.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [743.fdf63b48b024dcee.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [309.779ad7827ed03b25.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [113.6b7640af318460d4.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [157.d2cc755d1a6773e4.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [25.f5cef5ba11c3a06a.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [603.3c2aede976565e96.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [1.7aea729cbcadcc79.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [149.eb981261d6c45b1c.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [768.6109a3d5332b812f.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [207.0ead7a0098a1a450.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [170.b6bd455bd0c46a33.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [230.fcb1741ff04bda7a.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Optimization error [742.0dfe242f7784b20e.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:04 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-28T04:58:49-05:00
```

1. I use: generator-jhipster: "7.9.3"
   webpack: "5.74.0"
   webpack-bundle-analyzer: "4.6.1"
   OS: windows 10
2. It's compile successfull on dev, but not on prod.

IT's seem like a webpack problem, i got this trace in the end of the stack trace:
(webapp build prod) on project guineeinfo: Failed to run task: 'npm run webapp:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Have you tried to run `npm run webapp:prod` manually not through maven to see if you get more info?

Comment: Yes, i run it and got same errors.

Comment: Don't you get any error before what you pasted here? Please post full log.

Comment: It's a full log, i put the first message i've got before the errors.

Comment: I found another detail, when I use command mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true , project build and generate jar in dev mode. and when I add the -Pprod option (mvn clean install -Pprod -Dmaven.test.skip=true) the same errors occur.

Comment: When you run `ng build --configuration production` manually, have you checked which files are generated in target\classes\static ? Also I wonder whether you could have a different version of angular cli installed globally versus the one in your project: please compare global `ng --version` with local `npm run ng --version`

Comment: When i run: ng build --configuration production, the static folder is not created. And my global angular is diffrent of my locally used:  "Your global Angular CLI version (15.0.2) is greater than your local version (14.2.1). The local Angular CLI version is used".

Comment: I use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58538318/angular-8-webpack-bundle-analyzer-looking-for-wrong-polyfill-files to change my  "module": "esNext", and "target": "es5" in tsconfig.json file and it work fine. Thank's @GaëlMarziou for the support.

Answer (score 1):

If you have these errors, verify if in your tsconfig.json you have "target": "es2020", "module": "es2020" if so, change to "target": "es6", "module": "esnext".